# Entity Framework save related data foreignkey issue

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I  post a related entity with the postman. The `cart` gets id but the related entity doesn't get the `foreign key`. It saves the `cart` but doesn't save the `product` and doesn't give any error.

****`Postman`****

```
{
    "userId": 2,
    "createdDate": "2021-05-24T00:00:00",
    "products": [
        {
            "serialNumber": "000000499",
            "stockCode": "SP150049  ",
            "quantity": 1,
            "productOptions": null
        }
    ]
}
```

CartManager

```
        {
            // cart.Date = DateTime.Now;
            _cartDal.Add(cart);
            return new SuccessResult(Messages.ProductAdded);
        }
```

CartController

```
        public IActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart)
        {
            
            var result = _cartService.Add(cart);
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

```
 public interface ICartService
    {
        IResult Add(Cart cart);

        IResult Delete(Cart cart);

        public IDataResult<List<CartDTO>> GetCartByUserId(int userid);
        public IDataResult<List<CartDTO>> GetAllCarts();
    }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=BILGISLEM;Database=AlplerVT;Trusted_Connection=true");
        }

        public DbSet<Option> Options { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OperationClaim> OperationClaims { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserOperationClaim> UserOperationClaims { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserCart> UserCarts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductOption> ProductOptions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
```

[Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krNzD.png)

```
  public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            //IDisposable pattern implementation of c#
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                var addedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return entity;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post the code as text, not as images, Thank you.

Comment: I have edited. also added CartController Need CartService too?

Comment: Yes, please, add CartService as well as Configuration of DbContext

Comment: @TimurUmerov I have edited

Comment: Thanks, don't see anything problematic here. And I've just tested myself, it does add the related entity correctly for me. Are you doing somethinh except adding entry to the context and then calling SaveChanges?

Comment: @TimurUmerov It shows cart id empty in product  i will add the photo of debug can you please check it

Comment: That's odd. Can i see implementation of `Add` in your DAL

Comment: @TimurUmerov Should i do anythin in dbContext /  OnModelCreating ?

Comment: Implementation, not the interface)

Comment: Well, you can try adding this code in OnModelCreating: `modelBuilder.Entity<Cart>().HasMany(x => x.Products).WithOne(x => x.Cart).HasForeignKey(x => x.CartId);`. But I'm not sure that will help (only if your configuration was initially done incorrect somehow)

Comment: @TimurUmerov Yes it did not work :( still  product.cartid is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem the issue was context.Entry(entity). I just changed context.Entry(entity)

***`Not working`***

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
        {
             using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                var addedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return entity;
            }
        }
```

***`Working`***

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                context.Add(entity);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return entity;
            }
        }
```